# Asking for review or testing help ethics

Tags: discussion, etiquette

Is it ok to ask people if they want to write their opinions about website design, overall review, or maybe ask for some page testing help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Our FAQ](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/faq) indicates that questions should be practical and answerable - for example: "How do I resolve ____ error?"

Questions which solicit opinions (as in the case of asking for a review or page testing help) are a better fit for a forum site or to [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/524/webmasters).